# How can i override the margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; css styles from main body css for ul li

Tags: html, css

I was creating a ul li list, but my issue is that list is not working because it calls some other css.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fj6upcwd/)

```css
body, div, span, ul, li, input, a, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, img, table, tr, th, td {
    border: 0 none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="" class="">
<li><p>Laparoscopic Surgery</p></li>
 <ul>
  <li>Hernia</li>
   <ul>
    <li>Inguinal</li>
    <li>Femoral</li>
    <li>Incisional</li>
    <li>Hiatal</li>
    <li>Umbilical</li>
   </ul>
  <li>Cholecystectomy    (Gallbladder removal)</li>
  <li>Lysis of Adhesion</li>
  <li>Appendectomy</li>
  <li>Ectopic Pregnancy</li>
  <li>Myomectomy (removal of tumor (usually fibroid) in uterus)</li>
  <li>Oopherectomy / Salpingectomy ( Ovary/ Fallopian tubes)</li>
  <li>Ovarian Cyst  (Resection / cystectomy)</li>
  <li>Splenectomy  (spleen)</li>
  <li>Tubal Ligation</li>
 </ul>


 
<li>• Thyroidectomy  (thyroid)</li>
<li>• Abdominal Surgery</li>
<li>o Open vs. Laparoscopic</li>
<li>? Splenectomy</li>
<li>? Appendectomy</li>
<li>• Septoplasty -  Tonsil & Adenoid</li>
<li>• Rhinoplasty   (nose)</li>
<li>• Vein Ligation and stripping (varicose or esophageal)</li>
<li>• Insertion of Pacemaker</li>
<li>• Cesarean Section</li>
<li>• Hysterectomy – abdominal or vaginal</li>
<li>• D & C ( Dilitation & Curettage,  possible miscarriage)</li>
<li>• I & D – skin /subcutaneous abscess or cyst   (Incision & Drainage)</li>
<li>• Cataract Extraction</li>
<li>• Retinal Detachment</li>
</ul>
```

So how can i override the margin: 0;padding: 0; border: 0; , so that i can get the list formatted easily.

Removing
`padding:0;` solve my query but I want to use it for my global CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either remove ul and li from the global declaration or add "!important" to the new declaration to be sure that the previous rule is not considered;

```
ul{
   padding: 10px !important;
}
```

to make an example.

Comment: Use common sense instead of `!important`. Simply placing the rule after the body... rule is sufficient.

Comment: While `!important` will work, it's better to be a bit more specific (if possible) in your class definition. `body ul` will be enough in this case. `!important` should be avoided when possible.

Comment: @Lelio Faieta Thanks this worked for me. Thou I have not used !important

Comment: Normally it works this way but since I haven't seen your full css important was the only bulletproof solution

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to all list elements instead of using !important:

```
<ul class="list">
```

and add rule for .list class:

```
.list {
    margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    list-style: none;
}
```